# How to add two number so that every time sum greater than 0.5 counts as 1?

Tags: java

Ok let's say like this,

```
6x = y;
```

So, what i want is:

```
x = 0.1y;
2x = 0.2y;
3x = 0.3y;
4x = 0.4y;
5x = 0.5y;
6x = y;
7x = 1.1y;
```

And so on.

I know to add two numbers but what i want in my program is:

```
3.5y + 1.4y = 5.3y    // not equal to 4.9
33.3 + 45.3 = 79      // not 78.6    
40.5 + 34.5 = 75.4    // not 75
6.5y = (6.5*6)x = 41x // not 39x
```

ok whoever didn't understand my question i want to try it once again:

```
1 minutes = 60 second   // ever one can understand.

and 90 second = 1 min 30 sec   // easy enough

if i denote 1 min 30 sec as 1.30 min       //  just example for my question.
```

and i need to add

```
1.30 + 0.30 it will be 1.60 that means 2 minutes.

so, 1.30 + 0.30 = 2;

now 3.50 + 1.40 = 5.30  // according to equation as simple as that.
```

and the question is how to make a java program to do the above mathematics as i want????

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me.

Comment: use variables for x and y, like using a and b for example `ax + by`

Comment: Question is at top, I don't know how to ask better than this. I just want a program that add two number as above.

Comment: Under what logic is `3.5 + 1.4 = 5.3`

Comment: @Nawa combing 3.5 and 1.4 and getting 5.3 is not adding.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Under the logic described in the question. It seems to me like he wishes perform addition by interpreting the fraction part as base 6 while interpreting the integer part as base 10.

Comment: @peter because 0.6y = 1x

Comment: @Nawa how does that make any difference as `x` is not mentioned in `3.5y + 1.4y = 5.3y` If `4.9y = 5.3y` you can determine that `y = 0`

Comment: @Nawa to avoid confusion, can you write the question using generally accepted mathematics concepts like algebra.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ok  do you watch circket?? If yes you know 6 ball = 1 over. Now 3.5 overs equal to how many balls?? Ball is integer value

Comment: @Nawa but when did 3.5 balls plus 1.4 balls become 5.3 balls instead of 4.9 balls?

Comment: @PeterLawrey 3.5 and 1.4 are not a value of balls its over and how can over be 4.9 if 6 balls makes it 1 over.

Comment: @Nawa You have `3.5y + 1.4y = 5.3y` and you have recognised this would normally be `4.9y` but for reasons you haven't explained you decided it should be `5.3y`.  This is basic maths, nothing to do with cricket.

Comment: @PeterLawrey now i edited my question so that you can understand what i  am trying to do? hope you can understand now and can give me a solution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes it is related to cricket , 3.5 over means 3 over and 5 balls in cricket. so, when adding 3.5 + 1.4 = 5.3 that means 5 over and 3 ball and in total 33 balls.

Comment: @Nawa I get it now. when you wrote `3.5` I though you were referring to  a decimal not `3overs + 5balls`  The simplest solution is to do all your calculations using whole number of balls, avoid using decimal notation as it is too confusion and print out the overs and balls.

Comment: I lost my 6 reputation just because people didn't understand me. @PeterLawrey anyway do you have any solution for my problem because i can't use whole number or like that. in circket over is add in same way as above.

Comment: @Nawa what is stopping you from using whole numbers?  Is this homework?

Comment: @PeterLawrey , no, i am not a student but i have great passion on learning . i spend lots of time on internet just to learn programming language and web designing. so i was trying to learn gui java and i was trying to make a program which calculate run rate in circket. so, sometimes i have to add total overs played by a team. and in circket over added exactly as above and user of program also tries to add in similar manner.

Comment: @Nawa so ... what is stopping you using integer?

Comment: @PeterLawrey if you have a solution give me a code not just a comment. i have two different text field where user give over played in two games by a team and it should be added as above and give a result.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the problem (and also avoid rounding errors as `float` and `double` aren't exact), let's instead express, say, 14.3 as two separate numbers: `x = 14, y = 3`.

It seems like your problem is that x is in base 10 while y is in base 6. In order to perform addition, we therefore convert them to the same base, add, then convert back:

```
// Input: four ints (x1, y1, x2, y2)
int a1 = (x1 * 6) + y1;
int a2 = (x2 * 6) + y2;
int a3 = a1 + a2;
int x3 = a3 / 6;
int y3 = a3 % 6;
// Output: two ints (x3, y3)
```

If you *have* to use the decimal representation, this should work for you:

```
double add(double a, double b) {
    int x1 = (int) a;
    int y1 = (int)Math.round((a - x1) * 10);
    int x2 = (int) b;
    int y2 = (int)Math.round((b - x2) * 10);
    int a1 = (x1 * 6) + y1;
    int a2 = (x2 * 6) + y2;
    int a3 = a1 + a2;
    int x3 = a3 / 6;
    int y3 = a3 % 6;
    return x3 + (y3 / 10.0);
}
```

Comment: @Nawa Cobbled together a method that'll do it for `double`s instead.